# Why is my app crashing at startup on another PC?

Tags: windows, crash, dependencies, windows-10, windows-server-2008-r2

On my dev box (Window 10 Pro x64 v1607), I have built a .NET app (VS Premium 2013 Update 5, Framework 4.5.1, Platform target: Any CPU) which runs just fine. (There are dll dependencies of `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll` (v 3.0.40218.0) and `Ninject.dll` (v. 3.2.2.0) which are in the same dir as the executable.)

However, I go to run the app on Windows Server 2008 R2 Std x64 SP1 (Terminal Server mode, local Admin permissions), and it crashes on startup (the .exe and above .dlls are together in the same dir).  The Server 2008 box does have .NET Framework 4.5.2 installed (determined by [this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx)). I get the following Problem Signature:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: MyApp.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 2.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 588b6952
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.36373
  Problem Signature 06: 583fd726
  Problem Signature 07: 27cf
  Problem Signature 08: 0
  Problem Signature 09: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.16.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Also, in the Windows Logs/Application, I get this .NET Runtime error:

```
Application: MyApp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
Stack:
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Object, System.Uri)
   at MyApp.MainWindow.InitializeComponent()
   at MyApp.MainWindow..ctor(MyApp.MainWindowVM)
   at DynamicClass.DynamicInjector73c5fe57e70845ecaa6b82291e882454(System.Object[])
   at Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(Ninject.Activation.IContext)
   at Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal(System.Object)
   at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()
   at Ninject.KernelBase+<>c__DisplayClass15.<Resolve>b__f(Ninject.Planning.Bindings.IBinding)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable+<CastIterator>d__b1`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)
   at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](Ninject.Syntax.IResolutionRoot, Ninject.Parameters.IParameter[])
   at MyApp.App.OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at MyApp.App.Main()
```

Am I missing some dll? Wrong dll version? Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: use remote debugger to step though code until you see where it crashes

Comment: `System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load` *is* user-land. Stepping through code helps, because you can see variable contents, or the current state of execution, when the unhandled exception is thrown.

Comment: @IInspectable yes, I was mistaken with the definition. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the missing dll: `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll`, located on my W10 PC in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Interactivity\v4.0_4.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35`. Remote debugging found the miscreant!

Comment: ok, so it was helpful. so next time don't complain and do remote debugging ;)